# Wordpress: Full width Is not full width

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm so confused, take this example

I had a page on WordPress that I wanted to turn to kinda landing page.
I hid the 
Nav Bar and the header 
I used this code

```
.page-id-58 .image-bg-header, 

.page-id-58 .hero-container {

   display: none;

}
```

It worked perfectly

I also selected full width while editing that page on the editor

I had to use the same color to make that page look like a landing page, so I used that code

```
.page-id-58 #content article { 
background-color: #000000 }

.page-id-58 #content { 
background-color: #000000 }
```

Here's the issue...

It is NOT full width, not as I wanted to be, there's still a lot of space in the left and the right side

As you can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/07AEt.png

What am I missing, please?

[Website preview](http://graspdating.com/start-here)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think I have provided a short code.

Comment: Can we **reproduce** the issue with that short code? No, we can't.

Comment: What about the website? I included a link to the page I'm working on at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Can't I seek temporary help? And then I can just delete my question. 
FYI, I don't have good programming skills, If you could tell me which kinda code I can include that would be great, I have a page inside my website, I really have no clue how to provide a code based on that, anything you could probably help with? I think you're an admin, can you modify the question on my behalf?
Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme is using Bootstrap 3 and so the maximum width is **1170**. If you want to change this to 100%, add this to your theme's 'style.css'.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container { width: 100% !important; }
}
```

Also your image dimension is low - try adding big image and check.

Check the screenshot below for the image dimension change.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set full width of your image then you should be use this css

Hope this help

Let me know further clarification

```
.page-id-58 img.alignnone.wp-image-65 {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank's man, you're amazing. It worked on the desktop. But when I opened it from my mobile nothing has changed to the page.

Comment: Why doesn't it change in mobile? I'm so confused